# Google Map API 3: Display marker tooltip (title) by default

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to display the marker tooltip (the title) by default in Google Map API 3? (Not the info windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using this library : http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries and happy with the result. For those looking similar should try this.

Comment: which library? There is a plenty of them!

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip displaying is browser's behavior - it is impossible to call it with JS.